# Defining Search of an RB Tree

Tags: python

```
def Search(root,key):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    if(root.val == key):
        return 1
    if(root.val < key):
        Search(root.right,key)
    elif(root.val > key):
        Search(root.left,key)
```

Above is a Python code that is supposed to return 1 if the given node exists in the Red-Black Tree and 0 if it doesn't. So the goal is, in the main() function, I will write

```
x = int(input())
print("Found") if Search(root,x)==1 else print("not found")
```

where x is the node to be checked.

Unfortunately, Search(root,x) is of return type "None" and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style..

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, since the issue was just a missing `return` statement.

Comment: I could not debug that out. Up to you now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot the `return` keyword for the two recursive calls.

```py
def Search(root,key):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    if(root.val == key):
        return 1
    if(root.val < key):
        return Search(root.right,key)
    elif(root.val > key):
        return Search(root.left,key)
```